# Bootstrap H1 Aligning Problems

Tags: html, css

I need help getting my H1s to align. My code is below. An image of it is also below. I would like for the Spencer Hiltbrand bit at the top to be all the way to the right. The Beautiful Websites, Inspiring Photography part the same it is now. I am using Bootstrap.

Homepage:
[image]

```css
.intro {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-left: 45px !important;
    padding-top: 380px;
}

.name {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="name"><span class="red">Spencer</span> Hiltbrand</h4>
                    <h1 class="intro"><span class="red">Beautiful</span> Websites, <br>and <span class="red">Inspiring</span> Photography</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Add the `text-right` class to the `h1` tag? Also why would you put a container inside a section. It's the other way round. Not to mention you don't close your `h1` tag off, you have `</h4>` instead...

Answer (score 0):

The following line of HTMl you have is invalid:

`<h1 class="name"><span class="red">Spencer</span> Hiltbrand</h4>`

You're starting with an `h1` tag but never closing it because you try to close it with an `h4` tag.  This may be causing part of your issue if styles aren't working.

To answer your actual question, an easy way to get your top brand/text to the right is simply to use `float: right` instead of `text-align: right`.

Comment: Nope, its like a margin error, I think, because when I push it more right with a padding tag, it just goes to the next line, no further.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code them, because based on what you have, the effect you're describing isn't present, so there has to be something else causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to align the heading all to the right, then you need to get rid of `container`, `row` and `col-lg-12` because they introduce `padding` and `margins`. The heading's `margin-top` has been changed little from the top. Please have a look at the HTML, CSS and its working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/3ptp9dq8/).

**HTML**

```
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div>
        <h1 class="name"><span class="red">Spencer</span> Hiltbrand</h1>
        <h1 class="intro"><span class="red">Beautiful</span> Websites, <br>and <span class="red">Inspiring</span> Photography</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.intro {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-left: 45px !important;
    padding-top: 380px;
}

.name {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

Still if you have to make use of bootstrap's `container, row and col-*`, then you need to modify the existing html.